# Docker container is not cretaed

Tags: python, docker

I work with a Python tool that uses the docker for project management. I run the setup process with command,

```
$ bin/butler.py setup
```

The went through seamlessly but when I try to install new PHP plugins using the `composure`, the tool doesn't find the container itself.

So, my conclusion is the tool is not creating the container properly in the first place.

I describe the process below for the setup. After the initial configuration, this is where it starts,

```
    # all done

    print("pull doker images images")
    self.docker.compose_pull(self.local_yml)
    print("create containers")

    self.docker.compose_setup(self.local_yml)
    print("setup completed")
```

This is the general command for the docker execution. I know it has a security bug, but, at this moment this is not the concern.

```
def compose(self, params, yaml_path="docker-compose.yml"):
    """ execte docker-compose commmand """
    cmd = f"docker-compose -f {yaml_path} {params}"
    print(cmd)
    try:
        subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True)
    except Exception:
        pass

   def compose_pull(self, yaml_path):
       self.compose("pull --ignore-pull-failures", yaml_path)
   
   def compose_setup(self, yaml_path):
       self.compose(f"--project-name {self.project_name} up --no-start ", yaml_path)
```

The printout provides with the commands,

```
pull doker images images

# We use a docker-compose.yml and perform the pull operation
docker-compose -f /Users/chaklader/PycharmProjects/Welance-Craft-Starter/build/docker-compose.yml pull --ignore-pull-failures
Pulling database ... 
Pulling craft    ... 
create containers

# We use a docker-compose.yml and perform the up operation for the project

docker-compose -f /Users/chaklader/PycharmProjects/Welance-Craft-Starter/build/docker-compose.yml --project-name p13-27 up --no-start 
Creating network "p13-27_default" with the default driver
Creating p13-27_database ... 
Creating p13-27_craft    ... 
setup completed
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file is provided,

```
services:
  craft:
    container_name: p13-27_craft
    environment:
      CRAFT_ALLOW_UPDATES: 'false'
      CRAFT_DEVMODE: 1
      CRAFT_EMAIL: admin@welance.de
      CRAFT_ENABLE_CACHE: 0
      CRAFT_LOCALE: en_us
      CRAFT_PASSWORD: welance
      CRAFT_SITENAME: Welance
      CRAFT_SITEURL: //localhost
      CRAFT_USERNAME: admin
      DB_DATABASE: craft
      DB_DRIVER: mysql
      DB_PASSWORD: craft
      DB_PORT: '3306'
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_SERVER: database
      DB_TABLE_PREFIX: craft_
      DB_USER: craft
      ENVIRONMENT: dev
      HTTPD_OPTIONS: ''
      LANG: C.UTF-8
      SECURITY_KEY: some_key_:)
    image: welance/craft:3.1.17.2
    links:
    - database
    ports:
    - 80:80
    volumes:
    - /var/log
    - ./docker/craft/conf/apache2/craft.conf:/etc/apache2/conf.d/craft.conf
    - ./docker/craft/conf/php/php.ini:/etc/php7/php.ini
    - ./docker/craft/logs/apache2:/var/log/apache2
    - ./docker/craft/adminer:/data/adminer
    - ../config:/data/craft/config
    - ../templates:/data/craft/templates
    - ../web:/data/craft/web
  database:
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8  --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
      --init-connect='SET NAMES UTF8;'
    container_name: p13-27_database
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xyz
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xyz
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xyz
      MYSQL_USER: xyz
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
version: '3.1'
```

In the summary, my base image is `welance/craft:3.1.17.2` and I use that to create the container named `p13-27_craft`. The additional configuration is provided in the `docker-compose.yml` file and I run the `pull` and `up` command with the docker.

I think the container is itself not created. For example, I provided the data for customer ID 15 and project ID 55 and the printout says informs `Creating p15-55_craft    ... done`.

When I run the command to see if the container is created from the terminal, I find,

```
$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
cf2ea4638772        welance/craft:3.1.17.1   "/data/scripts/run-c…"   37 minutes ago      Up 37 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp    p13-17_craft
4504ae62035f        mysql:5.7                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   p13-17_database
518e3535859b        mysql:5.7
```

So the information from the print is not correct and container is not created in the first place.

How do I investigate what is the issue here and why the container is not creating?

Thank you.

Comment: *"The went through seamlessly but when I try to install new Php plugins using the composure, the tool doesn't find the container itself."* How are you installing the php plugins and what error is it raising?

Comment: The tool doesn't find the container and bug come from there. Would you please re-read the question? I updated it from the output of the `$ docker ps`

Comment: try `docker ps -a`, could be exited

Comment: Also, per [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/), `--no-start:  Don't start the services after creating them.`

Comment: @C.Nivs you are correct. The command `docker ps -a` informs that the containers are created but also exiting afterward. Do you know why does it happen?

Comment: If something is going wrong, suppressing all exceptions will make it much harder to find out.  You should remove the `try ... except Exception:` wrapper if you at all suspect the `docker-compose` command isn’t working.

Comment: @DavidMaze would you please elaborate on what do you mean? I don't get it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `--no-start` option, and add the `-d` flag to run as daemon (background process). If I run my own solution:

```sh
docker-compose up --no-start
Creating alerts-cache ... done
Creating mongoClientTemp ... done
Creating apilayer_alerts-api_1 ... done

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Nothing is found, even though my containers are created.

```sh
docker-compose up -d
Starting alerts-cache ... done
Starting mongoClientTemp ... done
Starting apilayer_alerts-api_1 ... done

docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
af557a2add73        bdsdev.azurecr.io/rva_flask    "python app.py alert…"   2 minutes ago       Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp     apilayer_alerts-api_1
829da0fabe62        bdsdev.azurecr.io/temp_mongo   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 seconds        27017/tcp                  mongoClientTemp
cdb67a305233        mongo
```

Comment: Your answer helps me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I investigate what is the issue here and why the container is
>   not creating?

Your configuration seems correct and `docker-compose` does not report any error, its probably that your container **was created** but either **was not started or exited right after being started**. You are using `docker ps` which only shows running container, you will probably see your missing container by running `docker ps -a`.

`docker-compose` won't report any error if container is created (and started) successfuly but exited right after starting. If you can see your container with `docker ps -a`, try running `docker logs <container name>` to see why your container exited. The step to solve the issues afterward will depend on how your container works.